# google play game service leaderboard unable to get top scorer details

Tags: android, leaderboard, google-play-games

am working on gpgs, here i want all the details of a top scorer of the day,week,month in my game.
example getRank(),getScoreHolderDisplayName() etc.
how to get this details of each individual leaderboard
plz suggest some tutorial for it

Answer (score 1):

You can only retrieve total, week and day scores. So you can discard month from the beginning. to do that you need to retrieve first all your leaderboards and then each score that you want.

This procedure is not trivial, several methods, callbacks and JSON parsing is involved. I recommend you to look at the [GamesClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.html), [OnLeaderboardMetadataLoadedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/OnLeaderboardMetadataLoadedListener.html) and [OnLeaderboardScoresLoadedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/OnLeaderboardScoresLoadedListener.html) reference.

Can't find a proper tutorial explaining these stuff. The idea is that you need first to `loadLeaderboardMetadata` to retrieve all the leaderboard info, and then `loadTopScores` of each leaderboard and combination of time/social that you want.

Comment: thanx alex, for urs response on my issue, i will incoprate this & let you know